# Importing gmail contacts on android emulator

Tags: android, gmail, emulation

I want to import contacts from my gmail account on android emulator in the same way you can do it on `T-Mobile G1 phone`.

Is it possible?

[I have this question too: [pentium10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243782/pentium10)]
**I am wondering if there is a way to do all this?**

Comment: I've only found "import contacts from SIM" on my emulator from v1.5 sdk. When I logged in through emulator browser into gmail in both mobile and desktop version, I haven't seen any trigger to do this.

Comment: I was told that G1 phone by default includes functionality that do sync of phone contacts and Google Account contacts, I am missing that from emulator. I guess that this function must be somehow "installable".

Answer (score 26):

I don't know about setting up a permanent sync, but you can do a one-time import of your contacts relatively simply.

Go to your gmail account using a web browser, click 'contacts' on the left sidebar. Select all the contacts you want on your phone, and choose to export them in vCard format. This will download a *.vcf file to your computer containing the contacts.

Push the vcf file to the SD card on your emulator, like so:

```
$ adb push contacts.vcf /sdcard/contacts.vcf
$ adb sync
```

Then open the contacts app on the emulator, and hit menu, import. Choose to import from SD card, and the vCard file will be found and your contacts imported.

Comment: After trying to to the adb sync i get an error :
`~/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb sync
adb: Product directory not specified; use -p or define ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT
` which directory do i need to specify?

Comment: Use build-in "Contacts" app to import the file from sdcard. You don't need a `adb sync`

Comment: so there's no way to do process entirely from adb anymore??

Answer (score 3):

You simply can drag&drop it into the File Explorer view in DDMS.
Use a destination folder, which can be accessed by your app or the contacts-app.
That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export your gmail contacts as vcf (vCard) file (but not CSV file) and then import the downloaded file into nox player using the nox's "contact app" (if you don't have contact app you will have to download it from play store), then settings under contact on the right side, then import under manage contacts (--> this is located on the left side , downward) . In import you need to select the ".vcf file" option and then Drive if you saved the file on your google drive or internal storage if the vcf file is locally saved. this helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator image might not include the necessary sync provider. If it does, the way to trigger it will be to run the setup wizard where you put in your Google account email and password. One way to launch the wizard, if it's present, is to install [AnyCut](http://www.cyrket.com/package/com.appdroid.anycut), create a shortcut to the activity called "Setup Wizard" (if I remember correctly) and click on it. Of course, you might not have Market to get to AnyCut... you could do `adb pull /data/app/com.appdroid.anycut.apk anycut.apk` from a real phone.

Comment: still will not enable gmail to authenticate an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you sync your Android phone to your Google account, Google needs a unique ID to identify the device. Real phones do have a globally unique [IMEI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity) number, but all emulator installations are the same.

Try

```
((TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getDeviceId();
```

in a Context and it should always return 0 on the emulator, but a unique key on a real world phone.

Comment: I understand that this can be the issue, but I do not understand why google needs ID. What google account authetification details are for?

Answer (score 0):

Export your contacts as a vcf file then upload the vcf file on google drive.
Log into google drive on your emulator device then download the vcf file. You will have options to open with contacts or your file explorer. Select contacts. Once it is done you will see all you contacts on your contacts list. I hope this helps, it worked for me.