# Can i configure gmail in Android emulator?

Tags: android, configuration, gmail, emulation

i want to configure gmail in my android emulator, i went to the "Add a Google Account" under settings/Add Account, i have given gmail username and password, but after some time it is saying that "Can't establish reliable data connection to the Server" ? What is this error ?
Can i configure gmail in emulator?  please help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978877/how-can-i-configure-gmail-in-android-emulator

Comment: I have found anwser from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114052/importing-gmail-contacts-on-android-emulator?rq=1, wish u can find it too.

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can configure Gmail in Emulator. I had the same. Please go to Gmail client of phone and simply enter ur username and password and setup ur account.

Comment: added gmail account in email client, then opened again account & sync menu - there were no accounts again, so tried to create and succeeded at once finally. Before that there was always "Can't establish reliable data connection to the Server" issue. Just adding gmail account via client fixes google account creation?

Comment: yes you can access your gmail account only thru GMAIL Client not with generalise Email Client in android as per my experience

Comment: @Maneesh The OP is asking how to configure GMAIL APP. The steps given seem to indicate that OP is using default EMAIL app and not GMAIL app. So OP would need to first install GMAIL app on emulator.

Answer (score 7):

Your AVD's target should be "Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level ?" instead of "Android ?.? - API Level ?".

To do that open your "Android Virtual Device Manager" and edit your AVD.

Comment: google account option is not displayed at all w/o api level set, so the problem seems only with slow connection