# How can i configure gmail in Android emulator?

Tags: android, email, configuration, gmail, emulation

I want to send email from emulator. How can i configure the emulator ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just as you do it on any android phone,  remember the emulator will always try to behave as a regular device, so i leave you some screenshot  to help you out:

[image]

[image]

Then you just set your email and password.

**Update**
Seems that you are getting a "Unable to open connection to server.", please do the following:

- Check if you can browse with your emulator
- if above is true then try:
  email username@gmail.com
  Password: ******
  And on next you'll see a configuration where you can change the server change it to
  Server: **m.google.com**

Let me know!

You can also see the following step by step guide-

http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/06/how-to-send-email-from-android-emulator.html

Comment: Thank you for your replies. But i got an error ,while i am setting configuration "Unable to open connection to server

Comment: On the emulator - make sure it runs an image with the google API's

Comment: This is done prior to 3.0 in newer emulator (actually OS) you should have you option in Settings there is a group named Account there you should see an option for 'Add account'

Comment: do I need to do that for every time I run the emulator, or that info gets saved?

Answer (score 4):

first add an account through the accounts and sync. Then just configure the default email client in the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Emulator images don't contain gmail and market apps (and I think a few others). This is a common issue.

I think it is possible to get a few APKs and install them, but from what I know that is not legal - Google's license does not allow this software to be run on emulator. So, while it may work, it may be illegal for you to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.

But i got an error ,while i am setting configuration "Unable to open connection to server "

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the gmail a/c in emulator as you configure on device thru setting->Accout and Sync....

Comment: I am using in my emulator API 17.
there is no option of Account and Sync.....
@Vineet Shukla

Comment: @Shukla G: I have installed Gmail apk on my emulator, but unable to run it as it get closes everytime... any Idea how can I configure gmail on my emulator

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Gmail in Emulator. Please go to Email in emulator and simply enter your username and password and setup your account.