# Sending SMS through Android Emulator

Tags: android, sms

I have created an android application. Now I want to send SMS through it to a real mobile number... Can somebody please help me with it. The information provided on the internet is to send message between two emulators. But I want to send sms on a real mobile number... Please help me out with it.

Comment: The emulator has no mobile phone contract / number / etc, so that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The emulator its not a real phone, don't have a number or sim card so it can't send or receive sms from external devices. From cmd telnet you can use **sms send phonenumber**

EDIT :

```
 private SmsMessage[] getMessagesFromIntent(Intent intent) {
    SmsMessage msgs[] = null;
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    try {
        Object pdus[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int n = 0; n < pdus.length; n++) {
            byte[] byteData = (byte[]) pdus[n];
            msgs[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(byteData);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getDefault().error("Fail to create an incoming SMS from pdus", e);
    }
    return msgs;
}
```

Comment: so how can i enable sms facility in my application..any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand your question but if you want to read sms from your application you have to use broadcastreceiver. see the edit above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you couldn't send SMS from Emulator to real device because it doesn't have any number. I have added the code below which will be helpful to send sms from real device.

```
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, RoadMoveActivity.class), 0);    
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(sms_phonenumber, null, sms_message, pi, null);
```

Its worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Refer this Question for how to set up an email account in your android emulator  [How can i configure gmail in Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978877/how-can-i-configure-gmail-in-android-emulator) and then use the following code to send a email,

```
  Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youremail@yahoo.com"});          
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```