# Troubles with application installation in AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm developing android application. To test my app on AVD I need to install "Calendar" app on emulator and make syncing to google account available. After installing calendar app (`adb install Calendar.apk`) it does not sync with calendar on my google account. I tried to install GoogleCalendarSyncAdapter (`adb install GoogleCalendarSyncAdapter.apk`) but I had an error said:

```
195 KB/s (113455 bytes in 0.565s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/GoogleCalendarSyncAdapter.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

What the hell is this thing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/android-what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you've set up a sync-account (via the System-Settings, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978877/how-can-i-configure-gmail-in-android-emulator)) and check if your emulator targets the Google-APIs rather than the generic SDK in the AVD-Manager.

Something else you could try is to download a pre-configured system image that has the Android Market and all Google Apps (including the Calendar) pre-installed (looks just like a "real" device) following [this](http://tech-droid.blogspot.com/2009/11/android-market-on-emulator.html) walkthrough.

Comment: Everything is OK: target image is Google APIs - Level 10 and I'm signed in but I've got the same error.

Comment: I've edited my answer with another possibility (setting up a pre-configured system image as the AVD-target image)