# adding email client for android

Tags: android, android-emulator, email-client

I have a working e-mail sender but I need to add email client. On my emulator it says no application can perform this when I press my send button. Is it possible to add an e-mail client for emulator?

Comment: Refer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978877/how-can-i-configure-gmail-in-android-emulator). It has a detailed mechanism of how to get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you have to configure your Email Client..

- Goto Email option in Your Emulator Menu,
- Give your username password of any email account,
- Then after Processing,it will ask you to Enter name and finish this
  procedure
- Again run your Project for Email And it will Open the Email Client.

Answer (score 0):

Download a free email app like [K9mail](http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/downloads/detail?name=k9-4.001-release.apk) and install it on emulator. Search location of adb command inside android-sdk and Type

```
adb install path-to-your-apkfile.
```