# Does Android Emulator 4.0 supports Webcam

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am learning android on API-8 (Froyo), but the problem is the emulator is also for Froyo which doesn't include the facility of sending email from app or capture a picture from webcam.

I was wondering if I download the emulator for ICS 4.0 in order to run my Froyo apps, will this emulator provides the following features:

- Sending email
- Supports computer's webcam for capturing pictures

Comment: I don't get it. What changes in the emulator is the system that runs on it, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first of all:

- The Android Emulator is always the same for a given SDK version.
- It is the system that runs on it that differ.

[Android emulator documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html)

Then, to send email from the emulator please reffer to [How can i configure gmail in Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978877/how-can-i-configure-gmail-in-android-emulator)

And finally to capture a webcam's video, check:

- [How to use web camera in android emulator to capture a live image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276450/how-to-use-web-camera-in-android-emulator-to-capture-a-live-image)
- http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/09/live-camera-preview-in-android-emulator.html

Comment: Ok so I am now downloading android x86 emulator, so say it has things I want. But on its website there are different emulator for different laptop companies and Mine is not listed. What should Ido