# Import contacts from google account to Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-contacts-api, import-contacts

I'm using the Android Studio emulator, specifically a Pixel 2 emulator running Android 7.1.1 with Google APIs.

In my team we have a Google test account that has all sort of contacts that are useful for us for development and testing.
I have connected the emulator to this Google account (by going to Settings -> Accounts -> Add account -> Google) however I'm still unable to see the accounts associated with the Google test account in the device's "Contacts" app.
I've looked in account page and made sure that the syncing for "Contacts" is toggled on. I even tapped on "Sync now" but still I don't see any contacts in the "Contacts" app.

For comparison, we also have physical test devices in the team that are connected to this Google test account and there it works fine - the contacts are synced to the physical test device. So it seems to only be an issue with the Android Studio emulator (on GenyMotion emulator it also works).

How do I fix this issue?

I've attached two screenshots, one for the contacts app and the 2nd one for the Google account page.
In the 2nd screenshot there is a refresh icon appearing next to contacts, but no matter how many times I perform "Sync now" it doesn't disappear.

[image: Contacts app]
[image: Google account page]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing gmail contacts on android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114052/importing-gmail-contacts-on-android-emulator)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, as here I'm asking why the Google sync of contacts doesn't work on an Android Studio emulator, and not through a manual one-time import of contacts as discussed in the other thread.

Comment: Hey, did you solve your problem?